# Updating list view items

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am updating some data in SQL server database and then showing that data into a list box. It is updating the data but shows the duplicate entries(old and new both) unless I restart the windows form. Anyone know how to refresh it on a button click event?
neither refresh nor update funttions are working

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select prod, eng from comp", cn);
        cn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {

        listBox1.Items.Add((String)dr["prod"] + "\t\t" + (string)dr["eng"]);

    }

   cn.Close();
   listBox1.Refresh();

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have duplicate values in your database?

Comment: yes m sure.. i don't have duplicate values in the database

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redraw the listbox, try this:

```
listBox1.Invalidate();
```

This will redraw your control.

Try:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

before writing the db read items, **if you only want the new items to show in the listbox**, like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select prod, eng from comp", cn);
        cn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    while (dr.Read())
    {

        listBox1.Items.Add((String)dr["prod"] + "\t\t" + (string)dr["eng"]);

    }

   cn.Close();
   listBox1.Invalidate();

}
```

Comment: thankx it works, it doesn't show duplicate data but updated data is also not appearing in the list box.

Comment: @user3201916 try now. And make sure your query to db actually returns something.